# String from scanner to DataOutputStream

Tags: java-8

Trying to code chat in Java, but i have a problem with inputting strings from Scanner to DataOutputStream.
Client part:

```
public class Client {
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Socket client;
private static Random r = new Random();
public static int status = 0;
public static String nickname;
public static void main(String[] args) {
connect();
handle();
//   end();
}



private static void connect()
{
    try {
        client = new Socket("localhost",9999);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
     //sc - Scanner(System.in);
     //sl - nickname i want to put into DataOutputStream
        String sl = sc.nextLine();
        sendPacket(new Greetings(sl));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void sendPacket(Packet packet)
{
        try {

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            System.out.print(dos.size());
            dos.writeInt(packet.getId());             
            packet.send(dos);
        } catch (SocketException se) {} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
private static void handle()
{
     }


private static void end()
{
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

I am using package system to send information. Format of auth package is [id(int)]+[name(String)]
```

If i send information without scanner (like hardcoded name and id) it works.

Greetings packet code:

```
public class Greetings extends Packet{


private String nickname;
public Greetings(){}
public Greetings(String nickname)
{
    this.nickname = nickname;
}

@Override
public int getId() {
    System.out.print(nickname);
    return 120;
}

@Override
public void send(DataOutputStream dos) {
    System.out.print("GOT IT");
    try {
        dos.writeUTF(nickname);
        System.out.println("Nickname "+nickname);
        dos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void receive(DataInputStream dis) {

}

}
```

It seems like something stupid that i can't see, and it's driving me crazy.

Server's part:

```
 //For each new client new handler
public class ClientHandler extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
{
    this.socket = socket;
    start();
}
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {   try {
        if (!isInterrupted())
        {DataInputStream dis = new     
         DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        if (dis.available() > 0)
        {
            Packet p = PacketManager.getPacketById(dis.readInt());
            p.receive(dis);
            p.handle();

        }} } catch (SocketException se)
          {} catch (IOException e)
            {} finally {
        end();
    }
    }
}

private void end()
{
    interrupt();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

It seems like smt simple i just can't see. Like, there's something different between scanner's string and usual string. But theirs hex code is the same...

Problem appears when you write both INT and STRING into dataOutuputStream.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem is!

Comment: git - https://github.com/verygoodat/TestingSockets

Comment: @greg-449, oh, god, my fault. The problem is, that i can't send information from client to server witn scanner inputting. I mean, if i put some values in dos in code, it works. But if i want to send user's string it stops working just right before adding INT value to the dos. (dos.writeInt(packet.getId()) If i delete this string - it works, but i can't do anything without id of packet...